# netbeans always download files when run a project

Tags: netbeans-7

I have a maven based java spring mvc project. Whenever I try to run this project first time the console shows me that netbeans is downloading a lot of files like

```
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.0-SPR7420.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

It downloads every time when I exit netbeans and start it again.

Comment: Same here.  What the hell?

Comment: try maven command with -o, btw I moved to inteliJIdea instead of netbeans

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help